# DCount not finding matching records in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, dcount

I am not getting the correct value for DCount

Table is "Lessons":
    ID (auto) pk
    InstructorID As Integer
    Weekof As Date
    StudentID As Integer
    Status As Byte

[image: 3 records]

My function is

```
Public Function NoRecordsFound(ByVal instructorid As Integer, ByVal weekof As Date, studentid As Integer) As Integer

    Dim strCriteria As String
    strCriteria = "Lessons.[InstructorID] = " & instructorid & " AND Lessons.[WeekOf] = " & weekof & " AND Lessons.[StudentID] = " & studentid

    NoRecordsFound = DCount("*", "Lessons", strCriteria)
End Function
```

The function is called from the immediate window as:

```
 :Debug.Print(NoRecordsFound(5, DateValue("10/3/2016"), 17043))
```

The following select statement does return the correct number of records (should be 1):

```
SELECT Lessons.[ID], Lessons.[InstructorID], Lessons.[WeekOf], Lessons.[StudentID], Lessons.[Status]
FROM Lessons
WHERE (((Lessons.[InstructorID])=5) AND ((Lessons.[WeekOf])=DateValue("10/3/2016")) AND ((Lessons.[StudentID])=17043));
```

Can someone help spot the error in my DCount expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When building your string argument for the criteria you need to delimit the date value with hash marks (`#`). Also, to be safe, it should be formatted as an unambiguous `yyyy-mm-dd` date string:

```vbs
strCriteria = "Lessons.[InstructorID] = " & instructorid & " " & _
        "AND Lessons.[WeekOf] = #" & Format(weekof, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "# " & _
        "AND Lessons.[StudentID] = " & studentid
```

Comment: I had seen the # delimiter in some examples but couldn't find any doc on it.  Should have pursued.  Thanks so much.